# NSViewController not being created

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsviewcontroller

I am building a cocoa application with one main window controller with a xib. That xib contains many custom view classes. I would like to add an NSViewController to the xib, but i'm running into some trouble.

In interface builder I can drag the NSViewController into the xib, assign it its custom controller class, and assign its view to the appropriate view in the xib. Here's the problem: neither the `initWithNibName:Bundle:` or `loadView` get called.

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**
People seem to be misunderstanding the question so I'll clarify.

The window already has a view controller. What I am seeking to do is assign separate view controllers to several of the subviews. I need to know how to associate my `NSViewController` subclass with the appropriate `NSView` subclass (which is a child of the main window).

Or in other words, I am trying to use multiple `NSViewController` subclasses to controll many different custom views (one each) within a single .xib file. Those controllers and subviews have their own .xibs which should ultimately become visible in the same window.

Comment: From what are you referencing the `NSViewController`?

Comment: I am adding it to the xib file (drag and drop), and then assigning its class to a class I created using IB. There is a tab on the right side that allows you to set its "file's owner".

Comment: Right, but if you just drop an object anywhere in a `xib`, it's not necessarily going to render, especially a non-View object like `NSViewController`. You have to either instantiate the `NSViewController` from code (in which case your `xib` will maintain reference to it as `File's Owner`), or set it to be the `rootViewController` of your `ApplicationDelegate`'s `window`.

Comment: I'm doing just that in my app using the method described in my answer. One "top controller" and several "child controllers". I edited my answer with a sample from my app.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern I use for NSViewController is to have a xib per view controller. Then, when you need that view controller you `alloc` it and use the `initWithNibName:Bundle:`  method. As soon as you use its view, `loadView` will get called.

Example:

```
self.editViewController = [[[MyEditViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyEditViewController" bundle: nil] autorelease];
[self.window setContentView: editViewController.view];
```

Comment: This isn't my issue, I'm trying to have a view controller for a subview.

Comment: @mtmurdock Did you check that the controller component you dragged into the xib actually contains an instance of your controller?

Answer (score 0):

I used to get stuck with that as well and gave up on that thing - the blue circle with a white bordered view in it from the IB palette. I now create my controllers from code and only set a reference in IB to the owning controller class via the file owner: right click the file owner, enter the class name in the Identity inspector and then make a connection from the file's owner view to the view.

In your code you then do at an appropriate initialisation point:

```
[self setMyViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"MyView" bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]]
```

For your specific case this could be in `windowDidLoad` method when your window is loaded from its nib and ready for work. You can then add the view to your windows content view. Also you might want to consider to have a 1:1 relation between view and view controller. It makes life a lot easier in terms of maintenance.

EDIT: Like @pcperini suggests in his comments you can use the palette component, but you'll still need to instantiate the controller in your code. If you want to use the palette component, create a property in your main controller or AppDelegate:

```
@property (...) MyViewController *myViewController;
```

Add the line of code to actually create the controller (see above). Then, using the bindings inspector bind the palette component to the `myViewController` property.

So, what you are missing is that you are actually not instantiating the controller object.

EDIT 2: Here's the code (the awakeFromNib is the method of the top controller). It creates two child controllers each handling a different subview:

```
- (void) awakeFromNib {

    [[self startEndTopicHeader] setHeader: @"Event timeline boundary"];
    [[self startDateHeaderView] setHeader: @"Event (start) date"];
    [[self endDateHeaderView] setHeader: @"Event end date"];

    [self setStartDateViewController: [[EventTimeViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"EventTimeView" bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]]];
    [[[self startDateViewController] view] setFrame: [[self dummyStartView] bounds]];
    [[self dummyStartView] addSubview: [[self startDateViewController] view]];
    [[self startDateViewController] setParentController: self];

    [self setEndDateViewController: [[EventTimeViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"EventTimeView" bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]]];
    [[[self endDateViewController] view] setFrame: [[self dummyEndView] bounds]];
    [[self dummyEndView] addSubview: [[self endDateViewController] view]];
    [[self endDateViewController] setParentController: self];

}
```